# Can I use idxmax() instead of argmax() in all cases?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have discovered that `idxmax()` works in cases where `argmax()` won't (such as on entire dataframes), but are there cases where I need `argmax()`? If not I shall wipe it from my mind.

Answer (score 9):

There is a difference. `pd.DataFrames` And `pd.Series` have an index, which might not be consecutive, e.g. `[0 ... n)`, but is when you don't specify it during creation. Therefore people often confuse them.

Consider this parabola

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.Series(16 - np.arange(-4,5) ** 2)
```

```
0     0
1     7
2    12
3    15
4    16
5    15
6    12
7     7
8     0
dtype: int64
```

The labels are set to `[0 ... 9)`, because we didn't specify them. In this case, both `data.argmax()` and `data.idxmax()` result in `4`, because that's the integer position and label for `16`.

However, if we filter out the odd values, that the index isn't consecutive anymore:

```
filtered = data[data % 2 == 0]
```

```
0     0
2    12
4    16
6    12
8     0
dtype: int64
```

Here, `filtered.argmax()` returns `2` whereas `filtered.idxmax()` returns `4`.

This is particularly relevant when you want to reference `data`, using entries extracted from `filtered`. That is `data.loc[4]` will return the found value via the unfiltered version.